# I have a working Chrome react web-audio app. When run in Firefox variables are listed as undefined.Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api, p5.js

This application works perfectly fine in Chrome. When it is run in Firefox the referenced global variables give an error of undefined. I do not understand why nor how to fix it.

If you click the play button after the song loads it plays in Chrome. In Firefox it gives the aforementioned errors. Online version: 
http://wktdev.github.io/react_record/

```
    let audioContext,
    song,
    mic,
    recorder,
    soundFile,
    audioRecordings = [];

    //__________________________BEGIN helpers


    function stopAllSoundFiles(arr,prop){ // @Stop all sound recordings from playing
        arr.forEach((val)=>{
           val[prop].stop()
        })
    }





    //__________________________END helpers





    //__________________________BEGIN load sound via p5.js


    function preload() { // @preload is required by P5.js
        audioContext = getAudioContext();  
        soundFormats('mp3', 'ogg');
        song = loadSound('audio/song.mp3');
        console.log(song);
    }

    function setup() { // @setup is required by P5.js
        song.setVolume(0.1);

    }

   //___________________________END load sound via p5.js


 //____________________________________BEGIN Timer

    const leftPad = (width, n) => {

        if ((n + '').length > width) {
            return n;
        }
        const padding = new Array(width).join('0');
        return (padding + n).slice(-width);
    };


    class TimeElapsed extends React.Component {
        getUnits() {
            const seconds = this.props.timeElapsed / 1000;
            return {
                min: Math.floor(seconds / 60).toString(),
                sec: Math.floor(seconds % 60).toString(),
                msec: (seconds % 1).toFixed(3).substring(2)
            };
        }
        render() {
            const units = this.getUnits();
            return (
                <div>
        <span>{leftPad(2, units.min)}:</span>
        <span>{leftPad(2, units.sec)}.</span>
        <span>{units.msec}</span>
        </div>
            );
        }
    }






    class TimeDisplay extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.timer = undefined;
            this.startTime = undefined;


            this.state = {
                isRunning: false,
                timeElapsed: 0
            };

        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.startCounter();

        }

        componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
            if (prevProps.isPlaying !== this.props.isPlaying) {
                this.startCounter();
            }
        }

        startCounter() {

            if (this.props.isPlaying) {
                console.log(this.props.isPlaying);
                this.startTime = Date.now();
                this.timer = setInterval(() => { this.update() }, 10);


            } else {
                console.log(this.props.isPlaying);
                clearInterval(this.timer);
                this.setState({ timeElapsed: 0 });
            }
        }

        update() {
            const delta = Date.now() - this.startTime;
            this.setState({ timeElapsed: this.state.timeElapsed + delta });
            this.startTime = Date.now();
        }





        render() {


            return (
            <div id="time-display">   
              <TimeElapsed  timeElapsed={this.state.timeElapsed} />
            </div>
            )
        }

    }


    //______________________________________END Timer


    class Button extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

        render() {

            let recordingButton = {

            }

            let changeColor = {
                color: "red",

            }

            if (this.props.isRecording) {
                recordingButton = changeColor
            } else {
                recordingButton = {}
            }


            return (<button style={recordingButton} onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.buttonText}</button>)
        }
    }




    class App extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.playStartCurrentTime;
            this.recordStartCurrentTime;
            this.recordEndCurrentTime;

            this.toggleSongPlaying = this.toggleSongPlaying.bind(this);
            this.toggleRecording = this.toggleRecording.bind(this);
            this.checkedToPlay = this.checkedToPlay.bind(this);
            this.cueSelectedRecordingsToPlay = this.cueSelectedRecordingsToPlay.bind(this);


            this.state = {
                audioRecordings:[], // {timestamp: 0, sound: p5.SoundFile, checkedToPlay: false}
                isPlaying: false,
                isRecording: false,
                recordButtonText: "Start Recording",
                playButtonText: "Play Song",
            }

        }

        cueSelectedRecordingsToPlay(arr = this.state.audioRecordings){

            arr.forEach((val)=>{
                console.log("Time stamps: " + val.timestamp);
               if(val.checkedToPlay){
                   val.sound.play(val.timestamp)
               }
            })
        }



        toggleSongPlaying() {
            var isPlaying = this.state.isPlaying;

            if (!isPlaying) {

                this.setState({
                    isPlaying: true,
                    playButtonText: "Stop Song",
                });

               this.playStartCurrentTime = audioContext.currentTime;
               console.log(this.playStartCurrentTime);
               this.cueSelectedRecordingsToPlay();
               song.play()

            } else {

                this.setState({
                    isPlaying: false,
                    playButtonText: "Play Song"
                })

                //___________________________BEGIN if recording when playing stops... then stop recording too

                if(this.state.isRecording){
                      this.setState({
                    isRecording: false,
                    recordButtonText: "Start Recording"
                });

                recorder.stop();






                //_____________________________BEGIN update state
                let timeStamp =  Math.abs(this.recordStartCurrentTime - this.playStartCurrentTime);

                let tempAudioRecordings = this.state.audioRecordings;
                tempAudioRecordings.push({timestamp:timeStamp,sound:soundFile,checkedToPlay:false});
                this.setState({
                    audioRecordings:tempAudioRecordings 
                });


                //_____________________________END update state



                //___________________________END if recording when playing stops... then stop recording too


                }

                stopAllSoundFiles(this.state.audioRecordings,'sound');



                song.stop();

            }

        }


        toggleRecording() {

            var isRecording = this.state.isRecording;
            if (!isRecording) {

                this.setState({
                    isRecording: true,

                    recordButtonText: "Stop Recording",
                });

               this.cueSelectedRecordingsToPlay();

                // audioRecorder.record();
                mic = new p5.AudioIn();
                mic.start();
                recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
                recorder.setInput(mic);
                soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();
                this.recordStartCurrentTime = audioContext.currentTime
                recorder.record(soundFile);




            } else {

                this.setState({
                    isRecording: false,
                    recordButtonText: "Start Recording"
                });

                recorder.stop();

                console.log();
                let timeStamp =  Math.abs(this.recordStartCurrentTime - this.playStartCurrentTime);


                //_____________________________BEGIN update state

                let tempAudioRecordings = this.state.audioRecordings;
                tempAudioRecordings.push({timestamp:timeStamp,sound:soundFile,checkedToPlay:false});
                this.setState({
                    audioRecordings:tempAudioRecordings 
                });


                //_____________________________END update state


                // save(soundFile, 'mySound.wav');
            }


            var isPlaying = this.state.isPlaying;

            if (!isPlaying) {

                this.setState({
                    isPlaying: true,
                    playButtonText: "Stop Song",
                });


                this.playStartCurrentTime = audioContext.currentTime;
                console.log(this.playStartCurrentTime);
                song.play();
            }
        }

        checkedToPlay(index){
            let arrayTemp = this.state.audioRecordings;
            if(!arrayTemp[index].checkedToPlay){
                arrayTemp[index].checkedToPlay = true;
            }else{
                arrayTemp[index].checkedToPlay = false;
            }

            this.setState({
                audioRecordings:arrayTemp
            })

            console.log(this.state.audioRecordings[index].checkedToPlay);

        }



        render() {

            console.log(this.state.audioRecordings);
            const mainContainer = {
                width: "700px",
                margin: "0 auto",
                height: "300px",
                outlineStyle: "solid"
            }

           let listRecordings = this.state.audioRecordings.map((val,index)=>{
                   return <li key={index}>recording number: {index+1} timestamp: {val.timestamp} | PLAY <input type='checkbox' onChange={()=>this.checkedToPlay(index)}></input></li>
           })

            return (
            <main style = {mainContainer}> 

                 <section>
                    <div className="buttonContainer">
                      <TimeDisplay isPlaying = {this.state.isPlaying}/>
                      <Button buttonText = {this.state.recordButtonText} onClick={this.toggleRecording} isRecording={this.state.isRecording}/> 
                      <Button buttonText = {this.state.playButtonText} onClick={this.toggleSongPlaying} />
                    </div>
                 </section>

                 <ul>
                  {listRecordings}
                 </ul>

            </main>

            )
        }
    }



    ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
        <App/>
    </div>,
        document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: I am not sure why that is, when I run it locally it is not an issue. When I refresh the github link it loads the file and runs.

Comment: Hmm working now. Not sure what was wrong the first time.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox does not read script tags of type="text/babel".
The solution is to run the app off a node server with a package that does the compilation work for you. I used create-react-app.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app